# Application Localization in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am close to end of my ASP.net project, and now I am approaching to part where i need to translate my application.

My idea is to keep ID of control in my database table, on a page load I am simply taking "LanguageID" from Session variable that I stored earlier and make simply query to Database and end up with DataTable that looks like

```
ControlID     |     Text
--------------------------------
tabAutoMail   | E-MAIL PATTERN
tabUser       | LOG IN
lblSignIn     | Please sign in
lblinputEmail | Email address
```

But my problem here now is that, I don't know how to start next ... if i go with something like this

```
foreach (Control ctrl in Page.Controls)
{
    foreach (DataRow item in StaticTranslate.Rows)
    {
        if (ctrl.ID == item[0].ToString())
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Control doesn't have property of "Text", so I can't manually set it, if I go with something like this

```
foreach (DataRow item in StaticTranslate.Rows)
{ 
    var Test = this.Page.FindControl(item[0].ToString());
}
```

Again I end up with same problem, I don't know type of control and I can't cast "test" to proper control type

Can you please advice how to approach from here?
Thank you

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you aren't using one of the standard methods of localisation (e.g. resource files)?

Comment: Idea is that admin of site can add new language, so he/she won't be able to translate it

Comment: Seems like a overcomplicated way to do localization... Your view should request the localized string from a provider, not the other way around. There are multiple tutorials on how to use a DB as a provider for localization (e.g. http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization-store-strings-in-database-or-xml.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for directions, will check it out right now

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using the approach you mentioned in the question, way too fragile...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments there are other ways of making translations work

If you want to make this work what you need to 2 is to store 3 properties

1. The control name
2. the property you want to localize
3. the localized value

(and of course the language selection needs to be stored somehow/somewhere)

The reason being is that some controls can have localizations in other ways than just 'Text'. (I might want to localize an image source for example, or the maxlength of a postal code textbox can be language/country dependent)

To set a property you then might use code like this.

```
foreach (DataRow item in StaticTranslate.Rows)
{ 
    var control = this.Page.FindControl(item["ControlName"].ToString());
    var property = control .GetType().GetProperty(item["PropertyName"].ToString());
    property.SetValue(control, item["LocalizedValue"].ToString());
}
```

This only deals with string localizations now and if i did want to localize the maxlength then i'd need some more work.

I hope this convinced you to go the route NGPixel suggested and use a DB as a provider. 
If that's too complicated you could even allow your resx file to be updated shown here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg418542(v=vs.110).aspx That way you could develop an admit tool to update your resx file and the rest of your site using 'standard' localization independently